# Proof that $2(a^4+b^4+c^4)<(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2$ if and only if line segments of length $a$,$b$ and $c$ form a triangle

Tags: inequality, geometric-inequalities, triangle-inequality

Obviously I tried to somehow manipulate the triangle inequality
$a<b+c$

$a^2<(b+c)^2$

Similarly,

$b^2<(a+c)^2$ and $c^2<(a+b)^2$

After adding these together:

$a^2+b^2+c^2<(a+b)^2+(a+c)^2+(b+c)^2$

But it seems I even work in the wrong direction, cuz I have to find the lower bound on the sum of squares, not the one on the top.
So then I tried to rewrite the triangle inequality like that:

$c>a-b$

$b>a-c$

$a>b-c$

and work from here but I also didn't manage to get to the point, where I feel like I have this problem in my bag

Comment: Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint.* For $a,b,c\in\mathbb R^+$, we have $$a^4 + b^4 + c^4 - 2\cdot \left(a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + a^2c^2\right)=(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(a-b-c)$$ Therefore, your inequality is equivalent to $$(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(c+a-b)(a-b-c)<0\\\iff (a+b+c)(a+b-c)(c+a-b)(b+c-a)>0$$ Can you finish? Why is it trivial that the sides of a triangle fulfill this inequality? Why is there no other option, but $a,b,c$ to be sides of a triangle?

Comment: I think you mean $a^4+b^4+c^4-2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)$. Clever solution, [+1].

Comment: Upps, thanks @Student1058!

Comment: You prove the product is positive.  That could be formed with two or four negative factors. So, we have to prove that no two factors can both be negative, which isn't difficult; but is that what you mean by "can you finish?"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

Comment: @OscarLanzi It is not difficult to prove that the inequality is true for triangles (consider the triangle inequality). However, the problem also asks to prove that the only integers that can satisfy this inequality are those that form a triangle. That's what I refer to when asking "can you finish?". This part isn't hard either: assume for the sake of contradiction, that wlog $$a\geqslant b+c\implies \underbrace{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(c+a-b)}_{>0}(b+c-a)\leqslant 0$$ Contradiction!

Comment: Where did you get that first identity? Haven't you just straight forward multiplied the right hand side?

Comment: @Ostap Just as Will Jagy outlined, if you know [other forms of Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula#Formulation) than the typical one ... you should be able to recognize it :) I simply find it sad that some (beautiful) inequality problems boil down to choosing the right algebraic manipulation... By the way, I've just noticed that you have not accepted any of the ten questions you have asked. You of course don't have to, but it is often nice to see one's answer accepted ;)

Comment: Yeah I knew the proof, I just wanted clarification of what was presented in the answer.  Thanks.